# If $Af(B) = B$ and the constant term of $f$ is nonzero, $f(B)$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ be matrices and $f\in \mathbb C[X]$ such that $Af(B) = B$.  Prove that if $f(B)$ is not invertible, $f(0)=0$.

I set out to assume $f(0) \neq 0$ to show $f(B)$ is invertible, because I thought it would be easier, but in vain.  I would be most grateful if you could give a clue.

Comment: Where does $A$ come into play?

Comment: @AlexR I corrected the problem statement.

Comment: The correct negation would then be:$$$$
If $Af(B)=B$ and $f(B)\in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, then $f(0) \neq 0$$$$$
(Unlike your title states)

Comment: My intention is to prove the contraposition, not the nagation.

Comment: He was trying to prove the contrapositive, not the negation. @AlexR The title and body are contrapositives.

Comment: This is a more general statement than the problem itself, and I strongly believe it is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$. Suppose that $f(B)$ is not invertible, i.e. there exists a nonzero vector $v$, such that $f(B)v=0$. Then from $Af(B)=B$ it follows that $Bv=0$, and therefore
$$0=f(B)v=a_0v+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k B^kv=a_0v\Rightarrow a_0=0.$$